# Publish Doxygen docs to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, doxygen

Our release pipeline is generating some HTML docs (currently via Doxygen) every time a PR is merged to master.

As we use Azure Dev Ops it would be nice to publish the docs there (in the Wiki perhaps?).

What is the easiest/most proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In azure Dev Ops you can publish a wiki from git files. See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/publish-repo-to-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#publish-a-git-repository-to-a-wiki-1

This would require to know up front the files that will be created by doxygen so that they can be commited by your doxygen pipeline.